# Retrieving an error from SQL Server in R through RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I have had some issues with some update queries that I am passing to `SQL-Server` from `R`using the `RODBC` package. Mostly they are server side issues and running out of memory. Unfortunately in `R`, I get no error message at all when I run my function, however if I copy the query into `SQL-Server` and run it, I do receive an error. My question is, is there any way to catch this error from the `SQL-Server` side and push it back to `R`?

Comment: You can retrieve an error through `odbcGetErrMsg`.

Comment: Try to pass one query at a time. When I have errors, the sql log is what I get.

Comment: @nicola thanks for that! I will take a look!

Comment: @YCR that is what I am having to do.

Comment: You right, I just don't understand why it is not happening in your case.